# Editing .desktop file doesn't do anything

Tags: kubuntu, .desktop

I want to run chrome thought incognito so I added

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito
```

to the .desktop file. This has, up until now, done what I wanted. Now, it opens regularly and even when I rename the file chrome is still able to open normally.

Any ideas how to fix it?

I am running Kubuntu 16.04.1

Comment: Hi @HanMah, which `.desktop` file did you edit? in `/usr/share/application` or a local copy in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: ...Anyway, most likely, a local .desktop file exists, overruling the global one. Good practice is to copy a .desktop file locally, edit that one, log out and back in. Please mention the situation, so we can provide this question an answer.

Comment: @chaskes I used a graphic editor (sudo kate) what is wrong with that?

I renamed it to del.desktop and then successfully opened chrome. I am still a beginner with linux but I would assume that if chrome was using that desktop file to open then it would not work after the change.
I double checked that I spelled it corectly

Comment: @JacobVlijm /usr/share/applications/
can you explain what you are suggesting that I do?

Comment: I don't know if this is important information but I open chrome through the plasma search

Comment: First we need to remove all possible existing local copies of the .desktop file. What is the output of `find ~/.local/share/applications -iname *chrome*`?

Comment: @JacobVlijm:
/home/d/.local/share/applications/chrome-pjkljhegncpnkpknbcohdijeoejaedia-Default.desktop
/home/d/.local/share/applications/chrome-apdfllckaahabafndbhieahigkjlhalf-Default.desktop
/home/d/.local/share/applications/chrome-aohghmighlieiainnegkcijnfilokake-Default.desktop
/home/d/.local/share/applications/chrome-blpcfgokakmgnkcojhhkbfbldkacnbeo-Default.desktop

Comment: Hi @HanMah posted :) Please mention if all is clear.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Your post was clear but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: did you log out and back in? It is quite impossible not to effect the launcher if you removed all local ones, there must be one left over.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I first copied the global one to the local folder. Did you intend for me to logout before then?

Comment: Nono, restore the global one, remove all local ones, then log out & in, then copy the global one locally, edit and log out and in again. possibly chrome recreated one or more?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Let me explain to you exactly what I did:
1) Removed all chrome files in /home/d/.local/share/applications/
2) Restored /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop
3) Restarted my computer (I have an issue with logging out but that is for another time)
4) cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
5) restarted my computer

Comment: 2 things. First, after I deleted all local chrome and restarted, I was still able to open chrome. Second, chrome still opens regularly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51527/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-hanmah).

Answer (score 2):

I would like to let everyone know how I solved this issue. But first I would like to thank @JacobVlijm for their amazing help. I don't have that much technical skills so I may be butchering the explanation. Please correct me if I am explaining it incorrectly.

So apparently there are 2 google-chrome.desktop files. One is saved in `/usr/share/applications` and that is the "main one". And one is saved in `/home/yourname/.local/share/applications` and that is the local one. I changed the main one before and I was told not to do that but rather only change the local one. The second issue was that in the . desktop file there are 3 instances of `Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`. I changed only the last one. In order to fix the issue, I changed all three, and now it works.

Comment: That's why I asked to post the (local) .desktop file. If there where no other local copies, it had to be an issue with the file. :). Only the first Exec= line is relevant in this case though. Glad it worked out.